# IDIS camera api documentation

Tags: recording, ip-camera, video-recording, desktop-recording

I'm Nimesh Khatri and currently I'm working on camera security system project. According to our client requirement we need to setup environment with IDIS camera and we need to record a video from camera through our application.

So can anyone provide us API documentation or link for that as it would help us to our development.

here is IDIS official link http://www.idisglobal.com/product/product_view?pgIndex=114

Thank You